# RAM: unit of measurement for size

Tags: memory, measurement

Just need it clarified with some references if possible, when I buy 2GB DDR2 RAM. Is the GB measured as gigabyte or gigabit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use 1024 [mebibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) [Gibibytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) (what we classically consider proper megabytes and gigabytes) (unlike the metric [gigabytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte) hard drive manufacturers use)

Comment: amm.. do you have any technical references? I would like to understand this better.. thanks for you inputs

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte wikipedia would be a start - there's further references there. I refuse to call the 1024 gigabytes gibibytes, personally.

Comment: Personally, I think the "classically" considered "proper megabytes" are just wrong. Everything with a kilo prefix means 10^3 not 2^10. The kilo-meter, the kilo-gram, the kilo-watt. And these multiples of these units were defined way before the computer era.

Comment: In this case tho, the 'classic' definition is the source of confusion and it feels like a convenient way to explain the issue

Answer (score 3):

Gigabyte. Gigabit is generally used as a unit in video game ROM size, and in network speed, and should generally be Gb, not GB.